# What's the correct way to paginate (particularly with JQuery and Jersey)

Tags: jquery, pagination, jersey, httpresponse

Just want to run by my method of pagination with Jersey on the server side, and JQuery on the client.

On server (assuming the user has just requested /rest/users?page=1):

```
    // Hardcoded the page number here, but it would be page-1, page+1
    String prevLink = uriInfo.getRequestUri() + "?page=0";
    String nextLink = uriInfo.getRequestUri() + "?page=2";
    String linkHeader = String.format(LINK_HEADER_TMPL, prevLink,  nextLink);
    return List<User> currentPageResults;
```

This gives me the following header in the response:

```
Link: <http://localhost:8880/rest/users?page=0>; rel="prev", <http://localhost:8880/rest/users?page=2>; rel="next"
```

On client:

```
 var xhr = $.getJSON("rest/users", function(allData) {
        var links = (xhr.getResponseHeader("link")).split(',');
        var relLinks = [];
        $.each(links, function(index, value) {
            var parts = value.split(';');
            var url = parts[0].replace(/^.*<(.*)>.*$/m, '$1');
            var rel = parts[1].replace(/^.*"(.*)".*$/m, '$1');
            relLinks[rel] = url;
        });

        alert(relLinks['prev']);
```

The alert gives me the right thing, and is what I'd use to generate my page links:

```
http://localhost:8880/rest/users?page=0
```

So questions:

1. Is my link header formatted correctly? Parsing the link header on
   the client side seems a little convulted.
2. Is this a correct/accepted way of doing this? I looked at the Jersey
   response filter, but that requires adding Jersey-specific
   annotations on the model class, which I didn't want to do.
3. What about total available pages? Is there a standardised way of
   giving that in the info? If I had the page total, I could presumably
   drop the rel links altogether, and just generate them client side?
   Would that be correct?

Incidentally, how did the whole format of link headers come about? The form "url; rel=name,url;rel=name" seems a bit weird to me.

EDIT: Found this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-6.2, which specifies 'standard' relation names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to ensure that these pages can be retrieved by search engines, I would recommend changing your links to remove the query string.

```
http://localhost:8880/rest/users/0
```

where 0 is parsed server side to the desired page number. As far as total pages goes, you'll know on the server if you've hit the end of your list of users. If so, just omit your nextLink. Likewise if currentPage == 0 then omit prevLink.

You can see this in action here: http://www.autoquoter.com/aq/en/Blog/Archives